# What's the difference between inject() versus __construct() for parameter injection?

Tags: php, symfony, constructor-injection

In Symfony services, I usually see parameters injected into the constructor, like this:

```
/**
 * @InjectParams({
 *     "someMember" = @Inject("%some_parameter%")
 */
public function __construct($someMember)
{
    $this->someMember = $someMember;
}
```

But I've also seen the similar

```
/**
 * @InjectParams({
 *     "someMember" = @Inject("%some_parameter%")
 */
public function inject($someMember)
{
    $this->someMember = $someMember;
}
```

with no explicitly defined constructor. The effect seems to be the same in this particular case, but are there any differences between using a constructor versus `inject()` in this situation?

Comment: Sometimes due to circular dependencies you cannot use constructor injection: the dependant object is not ready yet.

Comment: @zerkms can you explain in more detail? Seems like that could be an answer if fleshed out.

Comment: Say you have services A and B. A needs B to work, B needs A to work. You cannot setup both using constructor injection due to mutual dependency.

Comment: So which services are you talking about?  Symfony itself does not use Inject annotations.  Are you looking at a third party bundle? Bit of context might help.

Comment: @Cerad it's something I saw in a closed source codebase.